# Fade to black during animation

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

How can I 'fade out' (or in) my animation? For example, at the end of a scene I want it to fade out to black to indicate time passing and then fade back in from black for the next scene.

Comment: Just a quick reminder, StackExchange is a Q&A website, not a forum. You *can* answer your own questions, but you should still post a question and then submit your answer.

Comment: @Robert. I've edited your question to reformat as a Question and Answer format more suitable to this site. Feel free to edit it and/or post your own answer and you'll gain your own reputation from any 'upvotes' (the answer I've posted is 'Community Wiki' so I don't gain anything from any upvotes). You can also mark your own answer as 'Accepted' after a couple of days grace period. Thanks for your contribution to this site by sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

(from @Robert's original question)

I found an elegant way to fade to black.

go to compositing, enable nodes.
add an 'rgb' node and an 'alpha over' node.

plug the render layers node into the TOP image input
plug the rgb into the BOTTOM image input

animate the factor in the Alpha over.
you wont be able to see it without a 'viewer' node, but it renders nice.

and uh.. set the rgb to black, or whatever colour you want to fade from
or use an image
or a movieclip

world is your oyster